# strange issue with MySQL Auto Increment Id

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Auto increment ID column in my table and it does work fine when I insert the records using PHP. I have to delete the records from this table every hour using the DELETE statement. I changed the PHP.ini file and restarted the machine. For some reason Auto increment ID started from '1' again. There were no records in the table when I restarted the machine. I am using PHP 5.3.8 and MySQL 5.5.21 running under IIS. Please let me know if there are any suggestions. Here is my table schema.

```
    CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_location` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `test_summary` varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
  `create_dtm` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Here is my insert query

```
$Sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(test_date, test_location, test_summary) VALUES ('" .sDate. "', '" .$location. "', '" .$summary. "')";

        $Result = mysql_query($Sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $new_id = MySql_Insert_Id();
```

Here is DELETE.

```
        $Sql1 = "DELETE FROM test_table";
        $Result1 = mysql_query($Sql1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: show your insertion statement

Comment: didn't you re-create the table by chance?

Comment: check in your insert statement if you don't force a value in.

Comment: Are you definitely using DELETE? I know the TRUNCATE statement resets the auto-increment.

Comment: I updated my question with insert query. I am sure I am using the DELETE statement. This is happening consistently. I tested it several times.

Comment: Can you show the DELETE statement just to make sure? The table is not being dropped and re-built somewhere?

Comment: I updated my question with DELETE. I tried to insert the records manuallay in MySQL and deleted them using WorkBench. I have the same issue.

Comment: Just for grins do a mysqldump then post the test_table create information from it.  Might be a clue in there.

Answer (score 2):

Using a DELETE with no where clause is the same as TRUNCATING a table, hence they both reset the Next AutoIndex value for the table. (Which is what people would normally want / expect)

Could use something like the following to get around this in your case maybe:

> mysql_query(
>       sprintf(
>           "ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = %d",
>           mysql_insert_id() + 1
>       ) );

(If the DELETE clears the insert value then you will just need to cache it before your DELETE / TRUNCATE)

Comment: Would adding a nonsensical WHERE clause (`WHERE 1=1`) work as well? (I can't test right now, maybe worth a try @nav100)